# Delete all text but matches in SublimeText

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I am trying to delete all strings except emails in sublime.

So i can look for emails like this

```
[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'+-/=?\^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:.[\.a-zA-Z0-9-]+)
```

But how do i delete everything else?

Thanks

Comment: Use `(*SKIP)(*F)` verbs. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/WYmB19/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may do the following:

- Use your regex to find all emails, click <kbd>Find All</kbd> to select all emails
- Go to *`Selection`* and click *`Invert Selection`*
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to add line breaks between the found emails. Or, press <kbd>,</kbd> or any other key to insert anything to delimit found matches.

Comment: I'd recommend this as well. Depending on the size of the file you're working with and/or your reason for wanting to isolate certain parts only, it's sometimes useful to do the `Find all` and then copy/paste the results into a new buffer as well.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for a latest answer, after clicking `Find All`, then just do  `copy (ctrl + v)`, open new text, `paste (ctrl + v)`.