# Replace all words and characters except matching one with multiple occurrence?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I want to replace all the words and characters except the matching regex. i tried to implement negative lookahead by adding ?! but it's not working. Here is my Regex pattern [link](https://regex101.com/r/nF7hC8/21)

I want to replace all the characters except the having {{i18n sometext }}.

Thanks

Comment: Are you doing that in Notepad++? SublimeText?

Comment: Where had you implemented `?!` in the link you provided?

Comment: in Sublime text

Comment: yes in given link

Comment: Hi, I've marked this question as a duplicate. Please see answers on both questions and try a working demo here https://regex101.com/r/02fM78/1

Comment: You may use the solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52450052/delete-all-text-but-matches-in-sublimetext/52450696#52450696).

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew . It works :)